# Search/Match regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to match some special patterns in a raw text. But I found some problems.

The text contains:

> Ended recipe step 2 for material 1A121097-13 at elapsed time 20.43. Step type: EndPT,-7 waferID,-11 1A121097-13,-12 resourceName,-3 PM3,-9 timeStamp,+21 03/09/14  08:20:27.10,

If I use the pattern:

> `r'Ended recipe step 2 for material (1A1\d[Y\d]\d{3}-\d\d) at elapsed time (\d\d+?.\d\d+?). Step type: EndPT,.{68,100}?(\d\d/\d\d).'`

I can get what I want successfully. However, If I want to find out more and use another pattern:

> `r'Ended recipe step 2 for material (1A1\d[Y\d]\d{3}-\d\d) at elapsed time (\d\d+?.\d\d+?). Step type: EndPT,.{47,52}?(PM/d),.{17,44}?(\d\d/\d\d).'`

I can get nothing but `[]`.

Why?

Comment: Have you tried using a visual regexp tool, like [this one](http://regex101.com)? It will make it a lot easier to understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple typo. Replace `/d` with `\d`:

```
... EndPT,.{47,52}?(PM\d),.{17,44}?(\d\d/\d\d)
                      ^
```